# Can a row be locked so it can't be read [using Rails/Postgres]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm currently working on a rails API. I need to be able to lock a single **row** from a table so it can't be **read** before it is updated. I have to do this so the program doesn't retrieve information that is currently being used to make some calculations, thus generating incorrect results.

As I understand, ActiveRecord provides methods for implementing a **lock** with Postgres or MySQL. There's even a way for locking a whole *table* for reading, but I haven't been able to find anything regarding blocking a single **row** readability.

Someone recommended me to add a flag to my Model so from moment it is accessed it updates the record's column to `in_use = true` immediately. When the next query for retrieving that specific Model's instance is run it has to check for that flag to be false. My only fear is that there's a very small window of time before the record is committed that could lead to reading a row that is being used. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Look at Pessimistic locking in rails.   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html  does that do what you want?

Comment: Rails 4 supports standard SQL transaction isolation levels.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL does not provide a way to lock a row against all reads.

You can lock a row against reads by queries that use `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` or `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, but not against a plain `SELECT`.

If you control the read sites, you can as Doon suggested use [`SELECT ... FOR SHARE`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) for the reader(s) you wish to block when the row is locked, and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to lock the row.